# What is Java Mongo Criteria for the following request

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, criteria

I would like to use mongodb.core.query.Criteria for following request:

```
db.accounts.find({ "personalSettings.nickName" : "testNickName"})
```

My scheme of document is:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5354de90ad9b0f6c60bef7ba"),
  "personalSettings" : {
    "avatar" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/samples/avatar.png",
    "nickName" : "testNickName"
},
  "userName" : "testUser@testDomain.com"
}
```

I've tried to use this:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("personalSettings.nickName").is("testNickName"));
```

but i got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
```

personalSettings is a Map of < String,String >

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a more detailed stack trace. Also, how do you query? using a Mongo Template? Please provide an example

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mongotemplate. For example regular DAO request, it's working:

mongoOperation.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("userName").is("testUser@testDomain.com")), Account.class, accountsCollection);

Comment: We need more StackTrace. The Criteria looks good

Comment: @ArtemBilan, too long, so i've post into pastebin


http://pastebin.com/1Eg7nS0X

Comment: Which version of Spring Data Mongo and Commons do you use ?

Comment: spring-data-mongodb - 1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: by the way, why i don't get my value by this request: db.accounts.find({ "personalSettings" : { "$elemMatch" : { "nickName" : "testNickName"}}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public Account getAccountByNickName(String nickname, String accountsCollection) {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("personalSettings.nickName").is(nickname);
    DBCollection coll = mongoOperation.getCollection(accountsCollection);
    DBCursor dbCursor = coll.find(Query.query(criteria).getQueryObject());
    DBObject dbobj = dbCursor.next();
    Account account = (new Gson()).fromJson(dbobj.toString(), Account.class);
    return account;
}
```

For now -  only one way :)
Because MongoDB doesn't support searching in map by elemMatch and doesn't support searching by ongoTemplate/MongoOperation